# Swing and a miss LINQ to XML query

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML

```
<AllVendors xmlns="http://important/data">
    <Vendor>
      <VendorId>1</VendorId> 
      <VendorName>Vendor A</VendorName> 
    </Vendor>
    <Vendor>
      <VendorId>2</VendorId> 
      <VendorName>Vendor B</VendorName> 
    </Vendor>
    <Vendor>
      <VendorId>3</VendorId> 
      <VendorName>Vendor C</VendorName> 
    </Vendor>
</AllVendors>
```

and the following CLR type

```
class Vendor
{
    public Vendor(string vendorId, string vendorName)
    {
        VendorId = vendorId;
        VendorName = vendorName;
    }

    public string VendorId { get; set; }
    public string VendorName { get; set; }
}
```

and the following basic interaction

```
class VendorInteraction
{
    private List<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }

    private void GetVendors(string xml)
    {
        var rawData = XElement.Parse(xml);
        XNamespace ns = Constants.TheNamespace;

        **var vendors = rawData.Descendants(ns + "AllVendors").Elements().Elements().Select(vendor => new Vendor(vendor.Value, vendor.Value)).ToList();**

        if (Vendors == null)
            Vendors = new List<Vendor>();
        else
            Vendors.Clear();

        Vendors.AddRange(vendors);
    }
}
```

My goal is to return a List that would be projected based on a LINQ to XML query.  The query that I have so far produces output like this:

```
1 1
Vendor A Vendor A
2 2 
Vendor B Vendor B
3 3
Vendor C Vendor C
```

I would like each Vendor instance in the List to look like this:

```
1 Vendor A
2 Vendor B
3 Vendor C
```

I am not very good with LINQ and your help is tremendously appreciated!

**Update: Actual solution**

```
var vendors = rawData.Descendants(ns + "AllVendors").Elements()
                     .Select(x => new Vendor(x.Element(ns + "VendorId").Value,
                                            x.Element(ns + "VendorName").Value))
                     .ToList();
```

@AVD and @BrokenGlass got me very close but it seems that I needed to get the Elements collection.

Comment: Why don't you consider deserializing to your `List<Vendor>`?

Comment: @Munim Would you consider the XmlSerializer to be more efficient than LINQ to XML?  What are the pros and cons of one approach over another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var vendors = rawData.Descendants(ns+"Vendor")
                    .Select(x => new Vendor(x.Element(ns+"VendorId").Value,
                                            x.Element(ns+"VendorName").Value))
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This got me very close.  I updated the question with the code that actually gave me the complete result that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The values you want as constructor parameters for `Vendor` are themselves sub-elements within the Vendor element:

```
var vendors = rawData.Descendants(ns + "Vendor")
                     .Select(x => new Vendor(x.Element("VendorId").Value,
                                             x.Element("VendorName").Value))
                     .ToList();
```